# Xcode automatically converts the object to NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have been working on an app and during the development, I am facing a very strange problem. I have a `NSMutableArray` tempSortedArray, which is full of objects of `Store` types. All the objects are valid as I can see them in my GUI, the problem arises when I iterate through the array, at index 90, which can be generally anyone, the `XCode` converts the `Store` object to `NSMutableArray` object.
Any idea, why this is happening. This is the code to check out what I am doing:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cashBack"
                                                               ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [storesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

for (int i = 0; i < [tempSortedArray count]; i++) {
    Store *currentStore = [tempSortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"store class: %@", [currentStore.class description]);
    if (currentStore.cashBackTypeString != (id)[NSNull null]) {
          //do whatever is required to do here
    }
```

Comment: You are in some sort of serious misunerstanding. Xcode does nothing with your objects. At all. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @H2CO3: Do you think, I like making fun of myself with this idiotic question. The point is, I am stuck in this problem and I have no idea why, as for is there any chance that there is an array in the array. There is not! The list that I get, I am showing it to on the GUI and then I am sorting it and synthesizing the data.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have updated the code. Now check it out and tell me!

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid now what is `sortedArray`? And what is `tempSortedArray`?

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid How are you filling the `storesArray` array, that's THE useful question.

Comment: I get the `storesArray` from a JSON and there is nothing wrong with it because I have shown the exact `storesArray` on a `UITableView` before sorting them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see you changing the object type in your code. Are you sure your `tempSortedArray` consists only of `Store` objects? I would assume that your error lies when creating the `tempSortedArray`.

Comment: There is not, I have updated the code for you to understand it as well. Since the array is being shown in the GUI so I think is fair to assume that there is nothing wrong with the data.

Comment: @Farrukh Javeid: could you show how you created the `storesArray` as well? I think the problem might be there.

Comment: @Farrukh Javeid: I would assume that if you run your loop with the `storesArray` instead of the `sortedArray` you would get the same result. And another thing, your `tempSortedArray` is not created... I guess it is the `sortedArray` right?

Comment: I have checked them again, there is nothing wrong with the `storesArray` or the `sortedArray`!

Comment: @Farrukh Javeid could you show the Log for NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray)? Its really strange if there is really nothing wrong with your `storesArray` or `sortedArray`. I can't see the problem in the code you posted. And apparently so far no one else can either :(

Comment: That is what, has been bumming me for an evening now :(

Answer (score 0):

First I suppose that you need to post more code that contain `tempSortedArray`.
Also please check, maybe somewhere you set `NSMutableArray` as object in `tempSortedArray` instead of `Store`?

Comment: There is not, I have updated the code for you to understand it as well. Since the array is being shown in the GUI so I think is fair to assume that there is nothing wrong with the data.